# exporting a trac wiki and importing it to github

Tags: import, github, export, wiki, trac

I've seen that there's are scripts available for exporting Trac tickets to Github issues.

Does anybody have a proven workflow or script available for transferring a trac wiki to a Github wiki?

Answer (score 4):

Seeing that [Git wiki uses gollum](https://github.com/github/gollum/blob/master/README.md) that has support for MediaWiki, you should be able to

- export you wiki pages by

  ```
  trac-admin <env> wiki dump
  ```
- add appropriate file extension *.wiki*
- bring to Github as is

Comment: I didn't use neither Git nor Github by now, so this is untested. Feedback welcome.

Comment: This method generally works (i've actually gone through the steps to test it), although not all of the wiki markup seems to be interpreted properly once pushed into my github wiki. It does get it about 90% of the way there to where the individual pages could be fixed up when needed.

Comment: Well, what about wiki page change history?

Comment: We spoke about current content only indeed. I'm not aware of any Trac export for historic wiki page versions (other than moving through change history and downloading plain text by hand - not really scaling to dozens of pages with a lot of versions each). But with some Python fu you could i. e. adapt ticket export like done by http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/ExcelDownloadPlugin (see "download including history") to wiki pages.