# How do I export trac wiki to github wiki?

Tags: github, trac

I am moving a trac wiki to github. I was wondering if anyone knew of way to export trac wiki pages into something that github wiki pages supports.

Also if anyone knows how to export trac wiki pages into plain HTML that would work as well.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `trac-admin <env> wiki dump`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [exporting a trac wiki and importing it to github](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027148/exporting-a-trac-wiki-and-importing-it-to-github)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can load into Github exported with `trac-admin dump` pages as is, or rewrite pages to ReST|Markdown with [pandoc](http://code.google.com/p/pandoc/) (it seems, pandoc also have [preliminary support of MoinMoin](http://code.google.com/p/pandoc/issues/detail?id=170))

Answer (score 0):

The manual says:

```
trac-admin </path/to/projenv> wiki dump *
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**